# Windows Form Question,

Tags: variables, c++-cli, messagebox

Why does this not work? How do I make it work?

```
int guess = 0;

MessageBox::Show("The value of guess is ", guess)
```

Comment: What language are you using (C, C# or C++)>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
MessageBox::Show("The value of guess is " + guess.ToString());
```

or

```
MessageBox::Show(String.Format("The value of guess is {0}", guess));
```

Comment: Thanks alot, worked perfectly, just starting to work with windows forms, is a little different than basic C++.

Comment: The guess variable needs to be converted to string before concating.

Comment: Just writing it as MessageBox::Show("The value of guess is " + guess) worked fine. It shows correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `MessageBox::Show("The value of guess is "+guess.ToString());`